# MySQL \ join 2 tables and show results from 2 rows in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have 2 tables. One is a list of proucts, and the second - list of images connected to each product.

PRODUCTS as P

```
ID | NAME 
1 | apple
2 | plum
3 | carrot
4 | strawberry
5 | pie
```

IMAGES as IM

```
PRODUCT_ID | IMAGE | I_NAME
1 | 1 | app_abc.jpg
1 | 2 | apple.jpg
1 | 3 | appleonemoretime.jpg
2 | 1 | plum.jpg
2 | 2 | plum2.jpg
2 | 3 | plum3.jpg
2 | 4 | plum4.jpg
3 | 1 | somecarrot.jpg
4 | 1 | s1.jpg
```

etc...

Additional info:
 - Each product has min 1 image. 
 - The max amount of images connected with one product is 60. I would like to get: list of  products with image names **(one row = one product)**.
 - I will search products by product.id - I want to **get images in one column**, separated by commas,  **I do not want to get 60 'null' columns.**

For instance: if I search of p.id (1, 3) I would like to get something like:

```
P.ID | IM1.I_NAME  
1 | app_abc.jpg, apple.jpg, appleonemoretime.jpg  
3 | somecarrot.jpg
```

Is there a way? 'COALESCE' is good for this?

What I have now is:

```
select p.id
from products p 
join images im on im.product_id = p.id 
where p.id in (1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is your best friend, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT p.id, GROUP_CONCAT( im.i_name SEPARATOR '; ' ) AS images
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN images im ON (im.product_id = p.id)
WHERE p.id IN (1, 3) GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_concat` in query. Try this query,

```
select p.id, group_concat(im.I_NAME)
from products p 
join images im on im.product_id = p.id 
where p.id in (1, 3)
group by p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function

reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
select p.id, group_concat(im.I_NAME separator ',') from products p  left join images im on im.product_id = p.id  where p.id in (1, 3) group by p.id
```